# Detection of PQRST peaks in the given ECG data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, medical

I am working on an ECG analysis project using Python. I am totally new to python. And I am stuck at the very beginning.

Here is the data :

```
6262,6279,6286,6282,6290,6295,6293,6290,6295,6286,6282,6302,6299,6279,6285,6303,6293,6274,6275,6281,6276,6275,6286,6276,6278,6290,6293,6299,6331,6320,6316,6336,6345,6320,6336,6368,6338,6320,6348,6350,6340,6360,6376,6371,6376,6405,6412,6417,6433,6419,6405,6412,6412,6402,6413,6410,6376,6374,6389,6392,6386,6399,6379,6354,6351,6331,6321,6324,6340,6317,6286,6312,6312,6310,6307,6299,6283,6259,6262,6259,6238,6243,6252,6254,6268,6276,6271,6279,6300,6292,6274,6282,6266,6241,6254,6271,6269,6264,6282,6278,6261,6250,6231,6197,6185,6185,6183,6199,6231,6241,6259,6350,6465,6575,6757,6971,7159,7325,7509,7686,7884,8056,8112,7991,7826,7696,7538,7263,6994,6752,6510,6305,6185,6114,6080,6068,6056,6068,6116,6166,6190,6228,6264,6264,6279,6283,6278,6279,6296,6295,6292,6288,6279,6252,6257,6293,6293,6292,6324,6316,6296,6293,6297,6279,6282,6305,6290,6283,6307,6316,6303,6321,6336,6321,6300,6312,6313,6310,6313,6310,6300,6316,6334,6331,6351,6358,6345,6341,6357,6352,6343,6355,6361,6347,6336,6367,6376,6369,6382,6382,6374,6389,6407,6399,6407,6419,6403,6398,6433,6444,6443,6453,6479,6482,6492,6515,6512,6499,6515,6526,6526,6543,6551,6544,6563,6577,6595,6605,6636,6647,6646,6654,6664,6653,6653,6671,6677,6674,6689,6681,6673,6697,6718,6704,6705,6709,6697,6678,6698,6697,6670,6650,6653,6649,6649,6664,6639,6613,6612,6611,6595,6578,6570,6547,6530,6519,6485,6455,6470,6458,6424,6419,6430,6399,6386,6388,6379,6358,6365,6365,6350,6330,6326,6323,6320,6321,6300,6302,6334,6326,6302,6309,6309,6303,6320,6330,6312,6296,6313,6297,6289,6302,6317,6293,6285,6300,6303,6279,6300,6316,6295,6292,6307,6303,6300,6302,6306,6302,6303,6302,6292,6300,6321,6312,6323,6320,6299,6303,6324,6317,6303,6319,6320,6295,6297,6327,6314,6305,6320,6319,6321,6316,6317,6305,6314,6329,6312,6309,6324,6317,6305,6310,6324,6316,6310,6330,6323,6310,6323,6334,6326,6327,6329,6316,6324,6333,6321,6307,6330,6333,6317,6317,6340,6317,6313,6330,6320,6305,6323,6316,6302,6312,6323,6300,6295,6324,6326,6303,6307,6312,6305,6306,6317,6297,6306,6323,6324,6324,6336,6310,6305,6326,6344,6329,6314,6324,6319,6305,6317,6329,6317,6321,6331,6320,6317,6323,6334,6321,6336,6326,6313,6327,6345,6331,6312,6314,6310,6299,6323,6327,6312,6314,6321,6295,6299,6317,6317,6310,6319,6316,6303,6309,6331,6323,6326,6338,6337,6320,6338,6348,6330,6319,6340,6331,6340,6345,6327,6324,6347,6338,6331,6334,6330,6313,6337,6351,6351,6331,6344,6350,6354,6369,6388,6384,6379,6376,6362,6354,6389,6391,6369,6378,6389,6382,6398,6422,6438,6444,6461,6450,6430,6426,6437,6424,6427,6438,6413,6381,6391,6391,6378,6396,6403,6364,6341,6343,6338,6324,6330,6326,6307,6321,6344,6323,6293,6302,6286,6265,6276,6275,6265,6264,6272,6262,6264,6303,6320,6299,6305,6302,6283,6276,6276,6248,6252,6281,6279,6259,6285,6286,6274,6257,6258,6224,6197,6197,6199,6207,6240,6254,6262,6321,6427,6532,6702,6914,7093,7261,7445,7644,7827,8016,8126,8054,7889,7755,7623,7373,7084,6838,6601,6376,6228,6145,6097,6075,6052,6056,6117,6166,6188,6211,6245,6248,6272,6283,6282,6278,6297,6300,6288,6278,6286,6262,6266,6279,6283,6276,6292,6297,6293,6300,6295,6259,6258,6290,6292,6278,6305,6316,6303,6310,6331,6314,6321,6338,6333,6307,6316,6316,6293,6316,6348,6341,6340,6361,6358,6345,6362,6364,6354,6347,6368,6351,6354,6372,6382,6367,6388,6410,6419,6417,6426,6420,6433,6433,6420,6420,6443,6465,6461,6475,6488,6496,6503,6532,6550,6544,6563,6567,6546,6561,6592,6599,6601,6615,6636,6642,6656,6682,6682,6691,6723,6713,6712,6719,6719,6719,6735,6736,6723,6725,6739,6742,6737,6735,6740,6729,6749,6743,6722,6712,6723,6716,6705,6699,6685,6660,6666,6653,6625,6591,6605,6581,6563,6565,6540,6495,6499,6495,6471,6454,6450,6434,6413,6402,6399,6385,6385,6386,6374,6361,6362,6347,6350,6367,6355,6331,6348,6362,6358,6345,6345,6334,6334,6358,6355,6326,6333,6348,6343,6337,6341,6336,6336,6340,6341,6317,6329,6354,6334,6320,6334,6333,6340,6364,6347,6324,6340,6352,6347,6338,6343,6348,6345,6350,6351,6323,6330,6354,6345,6331,6357,6354,6341,6350,6367,6337,6348,6360,6362,6355,6360,6365,6358,6374,6382,6355,6368,6391,6378,6372,6388,6365,6351,6376,6389,6378,6389,6393,6372,6362,6378,6369,6364,6388,6395,6361,6362,6367,6371,6378,6374,6355,6352,6376,6382,6351,6357,6388,6376,6378,6398,6386,6385,6392,6375,6350,6372,6393,6389,6372,6379,6376,6374,6395,6410,6374,6372,6393,6384,6374,6384,6388,6378,6396,6396,6381,6398,6406,6388,6371,6395,6398,6381,6395,6389,6371,6393,6405,6391,6392,6396,6393,6382,6386,6396,6388,6382,6386,6376,6374,6374,6395,6391,6399,6412,6381,6385,6405,6410,6406,6409,6399,6391,6410,6415,6398,6407,6419,6410,6413,6419,6410,6402,6412,6422,6396,6416,6436,6434,6430,6440,6453,6437,6448,6470,6460,6462,6472,6446,6450,6460,6467,6467,6470,6479,6495,6520,6508,6501,6529,6548,6564,6548,6554,6534,6499,6516,6537,6517,6502,6489,6475,6478,6484,6475,6447,6457,6461,6436,6433,6446,6427,6406,6430,6453,6436,6438,6438,6393,6378,6417,6396,6372,6375,6376,6369,6393,6410,6385,6386,6423,6419,6402,6410,6392,6372,6375,6381,6379,6388,6410,6407,6392,6389,6379,6348,6326,6338,6321,6319,6352,6341,6345,6409,6493,6565,6695,6890,7066,7217,7404,7579,7734,7916,8057,8030,7896,7795,7660,7438,7184,6935,6732,6527,6368,6258,6216,6183,6178,6180,6216,6254,6286,6324,6340,6343,6391,6413,6413,6419,6457,6451,6436,6458,6462,6437,6437,6461,6438,6467,6489,6477,6460,6484,6493,6464,6446,6451,6455,6457,6468,6477,6465,6482,6498,6484,6488,6502,6488,6471,6467,6470,6471,6496,6496,6495,6513,6532,6526,6537,6557,6532,6519,6541,6547,6525,6536,6551,6556,6568,6589,6587,6577,6603,6602,6564,6584,6606,6574,6558,6575,6589,6589,6601,6620,6629,6646,6656,6653,6651,6680,6697,6681,6694,6704,6689,6718,6736,6749,6740,6773,6763,6753,6791,6833,6818,6821,6811,6802,6799,6825,6838,6815,6822,6808,6799,6811,6811,6814,6821,6833,6802,6784,6792,6795,6778,6774,6775,6767,6756,6756,6746,6725,6713,6723,6699,6680,6675,6649,6627,6619,6612,6592,6585,6561,6527,6532,6550,6530,6498,6499,6491,6465,6478,6484,6457,6453,6460,6436,6447,6446,6455,6440,6448,6465,6455,6443,6464,6457,6433,6446,6453,6430,6434,6436,6426,6438,6443,6426,6420,6437,6450,6434,6436,6447,6429,6423,6430,6430,6426,6436,6430,6426,6419,6426,6422,6430,6446,6433,6437,6441,6438,6424,6424,6441,6440,6434,6455,6434,6429,6448,6457,6433,6440,6462,6457,6447,6430,6424,6423,6438,6436,6415,6441,6436,6409,6405,6436,6434,6423,6423,6420,6398,6416,6436,6420,6399,6400,6405,6424,6433,6426,6402,6406,6423,6422,6413,6422,6420,6422,6437,6416,6396,6426,6450,6423,6399,6415,6429,6427,6427,6417,6407,6407,6430,6423,6424,6422,6405,6392,6416,6441,6410,6409,6430,6415,6407,6429,6415,6410,6429,6427,6417,6419,6417,6413,6420,6434,6424,6389,6396,6399,6398,6400,6403,6393,6400,6413,6413,6403,6409,6423,6396,6405,6412,6399,6386,6402,6400,6403,6427,6420,6396,6412,6415,6403,6399,6413,6415,6392,6385,6400,6410,6410,6430,6429,6427,6455,6447,6434,6451,6450,6443,6444,6438,6434,6431,6450,6464,6455,6478,6493,6489,6505,6517,6510,6498,6496,6489,6472,6468,6491,6478,6464,6443,6434,6443,6465,6451,6420,6416,6405,6398,6403,6392,6398,6392,6395,6375,6365,6367,6372,6347,6338,6344,6314,6309,6331,6334,6330,6340,6340,6321,6340,6352,6331,6319,6327,6319,6289,6300,6316,6320,6336,6327,6312,6300,6305,6288,6250,6237,6244,6252,6285,6295,6285,6321,6417,6502,6622,6809,6977,7108,7262,7451,7621,7809,7961,7968,7829,7696,7595,7417,7180,6924,6685,6479,6297,6176,6124,6103,6085,6069,6107,6158,6176,6202,6251,6266,6271,6300,6323,6297,6312,6326,6327,6320,6330,6310,6289,6313,6320,6302,6329,6344,6334,6326,6327,6314,6310,6317,6314,6305,6309,6333,6350,6348,6347,6333,6345,6372,6368,6345,6341,6352,6344,6343,6368,6369,6369,6386,6403,6384,6392,6403,6382,6371,6385,6389,6379,6392,6406,6398,6417,6441,6438,6437,6470,6462,6451,6461,6470,6455,6455,6481,6477,6484,6513,6509,6516,6543,6563,6546,6546,6563,6579,6579,6606,6613,6602,6611,6647,6660,6674,6687,6670,6674,6708,6697,6682,6701,6716,6699,6712,6723,6726,6726,6732,6720,6733,6736,6736,6712,6715,6713,6695,6682,6699,6685,6664,6667,6664,6632,6626,6627,6611,6588,6587,6574,6537,6515,6510,6485,6486,6482,6443,6407,6427,6424,6405,6398,6393,6381,6376,6381,6367,6348,6357,6351,6334,6336,6344,6323,6314,6340,6333,6314,6333,6321,6305,6312,6320,6312,6307,6307,6299,6296,6314,6309,6297,6299,6320,6299,6296,6306,6292,6282,6303,6305,6293,6293,6296,6286,6295,6306,6300,6282,6302,6306,6286,6288,6289,6278,6296,6302,6285,6269,6292,6289,6278,6286,6310,6281,6278,6296,6293,6282,6303,6288,6265,6279,6290,6281,6288,6292,6274,6264,6292,6297,6285,6296,6307,6279,6282,6293,6286,6268,6276,6278,6265,6272,6276,6250,6252,6275,6271,6257,6275,6278,6262,6245,6254,6247,6251,6264,6264,6254,6257,6251,6248,6258,6278,6259,6252,6268,6255,6255,6261,6259,6250,6257,6268,6258,6250,6264,6255,6244,6251,6259,6252,6251,6269,6252,6248,6258,6254,6238,6255,6248,6226,6235,6252,6233,6240,6252,6244,6235,6258,6272,6262,6265,6274,6250,6244,6268,6268,6243,6275,6276,6261,6274,6279,6258,6261,6283,6278,6254,6255,6264,6257,6245,6271,6265,6288,6302,6295,6283,6305,6316,6310,6314,6323,6300,6296,6314,6321,6307,6333,6329,6330,6345,6369,6374,6382,6410,6422,6402,6396,6381,6375,6384,6399,6386,6361,6347,6352,6333,6350,6369,6360,6329,6323,6288,6282,6302,6307,6288,6295,6300,6285,6288,6317,6286,6262,6266,6257,6243,6254,6255,6244,6244,6269,6265,6264,6278,6275,6264,6265,6259,6238,6240,6252,6250,6268,6293,6289,6265,6262,6258,6221,6199,6188,6171,6202,6235,6234,6230,6289,6379,6458,6594,6797,6974,7141,7303,7475,7643,7868,8044,8059,7950,7798,7662,7506,7249,6990,6743,6537,6327,6176,6102,6089,6072,6062,6097,6135,6155,6202,6245,6261,6268,6289,6285,6281,6290,6289,6276,6286,6286,6258,6248,6271,6269,6279,6305,6312,6300,6296,6293,6279,6285,6296,6276,6279,6289,6281,6265,6299,6319,6316,6307,6306,6302,6303,6310,6303,6271,6293,6309,6295,6300,6321,6307,6319,6341,6338,6309,6319,6341,6345,6316,6321,6316,6330,6351,6352,6343,6364,6375,6368,6374,6386,6369,6372,6399,6406,6388,6399,6427,6434,6429,6454,6454,6464,6486,6477,6460,6488,6498,6505,6522,6534,6526,6536,6561,6575,6577,6594,6598,6578,6591,6620,6606,6602,6613,6613,6608,6626,6619,6606,6612,6640,6618,6609,6625,6622,6596,6602,6603,6591,6584,6588,6561,6541,6550,6541,6517,6522,6501,6464,6461,6481,6437,6413,6412,6385,6361,6368,6367,6333,6313,6330,6317,6295,6300,6283,6268,6288,6295,6251,6233,6258,6251,6244,6235,6234,6221,6231,6234,6221,6217,6228,6217,6214,6238,6237,6223,6233,6241,6219,6220,6250,6247,6228,6238,6231,6226,6241,6244,6227,6228,6240,6234,6226,6234,6233,6213,6224,6241,6244,6226,6245,6234,6230,6248,6248,6223,6243,6261,6251,6250,6251,6230,6241,6261,6259,6244,6252,6250,6248,6250,6264,6250,6251,6264,6266,6247,6261,6274,6262,6255,6262,6250,6261,6275,6276,6258,6255,6255,6259,6255,6283,6285,6258,6261,6269,6266,6269,6274,6262,6271,6283,6268,6257,6271,6281,6266,6278,6276,6266,6272,6281,6269,6269,6286,6292,6269,6286,6288,6275,6285,6293,6282,6279,6288,6283,6262,6289,6300,6271,6265,6288,6279,6276,6282,6281,6255,6279,6295,6279,6278,6286,6271,6276,6288,6276,6255,6269,6286,6264,6251,6257,6244,6234,6254,6276,6258,6261,6269,6257,6271,6292,6275,6272,6285,6296,6262,6255,6281,6272,6274,6290,6276,6271,6281,6286,6268,6276,6300,6275,6262,6293,6303,6289,6300,6323,6319,6317,6337,6333,6331,6354,6358,6337,6330,6336,6337,6348,6365,6354,6365,6389,6391,6384,6413,6444,6424,6426,6433,6413,6398,6416,6422,6413,6406,6391,6376,6398,6395,6378,6371,6367,6336,6323,6331,6333,6324,6323,6321,6323,6319,6341,6333,6314,6306,6290,6275,6292,6299,6286,6278,6293,6305,6296,6319,6331,6303,6292,6305,6295,6285,6283,6269,6274,6299,6316,6300,6307,6299,6268,6247,6237,6213,6217,6262,6275,6261,6290,6358,6443,6553,6730,6922,7087,7276,7458,7629,7829,8044,8130,8098,7963,7822,7682,7479,7204,6928,6695,6477,6293,6203,6172,6121,6086,6103,6145,6175,6207,6244,6257,6279,6306,6302,6303,6314,6323,6317,6317,6324,6309,6296,6313,6306,6299,6323,6341,6320,6329,6337,6309,6289,6295,6296,6296,6296,6302,6295,6316,6338,6317,6330,6352,6334,6313,6319,6329,6310,6310,6321,6327,6317,6329,6340,6338,6354,6364,6347,6344,6350,6334,6334,6360,6352,6351,6369,6368,6357,6379,6399,6402,6392,6402,6400,6396,6406,6413,6410,6422,6441,6444,6444,6488,6486,6470,6491,6510,6506,6501,6522,6527,6526,6551,6560,6560,6587,6611,6599,6612,6634,6633,6620,6630,6647,6640,6651,6661,6647,6667,6678,6668,6664,6680,6664,6651,6668,6667,6623,6626,6650,6647,6630,6632,6620,6605,6603,6599,6579,6548,6547,6526,6501,6496,6471,6448,6451,6448,6419,6399,6393,6376,6360,6358,6338,6307,6312,6317,6289,6290,6296,6268,6271,6290,6281,6257,6265,6281,6261,6248,6252,6257,6255,6271,6257,6244,6261,6264,6237,6245,6266,6258,6255,6261,6257,6241,6247,6278,6261,6259,6264,6243,6237,6259,6265,6251,6257,6274,6264,6261,6265,6259,6257,6266,6258,6240,6247,6248,6226,6238,6264,6254,6224,6240,6247,6231,6238,6250,6206,6216,6247,6234,6233,6237,6228,6223,6238,6245,6231,6227,6231,6211,6216,6234,6227,6220,6226,6226,6223,6224,6234,6230,6217,6221,6231,6213,6217,6224,6227,6219,6216,6209,6193,6209,6217,6213,6207,6199,6183,6185,6219,6223,6197,6203,6196,6178,6192,6200,6190,6196,6209,6193,6166,6180,6189,6188,6189,6190,6175,6173,6185,6166,6159,6182,6185,6185,6172,6172,6159,6155,6176,6173,6165,6171,6176,6171,6166,6172,6164,6151,6171,6162,6148,6142,6134,6120,6140,6148,6134,6144,6164,6161,6141,6154,6178,6162,6165,6164,6158,6164,6171,6162,6138,6159,6180,6173,6168,6173,6164,6164,6179,6176,6172,6173,6176,6164,6166,6193,6196,6192,6203,6213,6211,6243,6248,6228,6226,6237,6241,6237,6245,6234,6233,6268,6279,6266,6292,6312,6299,6320,6330,6305,6290,6312,6295,6281,6286,6278,6257,6261,6271,6251,6251,6262,6247,6216,6207,6231,6211,6196,6207,6207,6209,6206,6209,6200,6196,6202,6180,6159,6169,6168,6161,6171,6182,6176,6197,6216,6203,6206,6227,6203,6189,6189,6185,6179,6196,6210,6204,6203,6220,6226,6195,6171,6158,6123,6123,6151,6158,6169,6210,6238,6296,6426,6587,6763,6960,7160,7324,7514,7716,7909,8080,8126,7995,7817,7712,7548,7248,6967,6747,6520,6285,6155,6124,6078,6051,6054,6075,6106,6162,6192,6211,6250,6274,6272,6289,6292,6289,6303,6319,6307,6286,6279,6281,6266,6288,6312,6305,6302,6323,6323,6317,6312,6296,6288,6296,6305,6306,6313,6329,6326,6319,6334,6337,6329,6341,6341,6317,6300,6343,6347,6331,6345,6372,6348,6372,6391,6362,6362,6358,6351,6358,6360,6361,6345,6360,6384,6385,6384,6406,6409,6400,6415,6430,6409,6417,6438,6430,6416,6434,6440,6462,6508,6525,6489,6496,6533,6532,6527,6556,6567,6553,6557,6572,6579,6613,6637,6634,6640,6658,6663,6671,6668,6670,6661,6666,6684,6674,6671,6684,6688,6677,6698,6691,6680,6698,6701,6678,6664,6680,6673,6651,6651,6657,6634,6613,6626,6605,6571,6581,6565,6550,6536,6512,6482,6460,6453,6447,6429,6409,6385,6368,6358,6355,6340,6345,6344,6327,6314,6300,6286,6292,6309,6290,6268,6262,6262,6254,6262,6275,6274,6272,6257,6271,6266,6276,6278,6259,6245,6272,6276,6251,6244,6276,6266,6271,6269,6258,6259,6279,6279,6252,6274,6276,6261,6271,6289,6292,6279,6300,6293,6271,6286,6309,6286,6303,6303,6282,6265,6268,6290,6302,6286,6274,6268,6275,6295,6295,6288,6314,6316,6283,6307,6324,6312,6299,6305,6307,6295,6314,6313,6305,6307,6302,6320,6313,6320,6319,6323,6320,6313,6300,6300,6312,6319,6316,6310,6296,6303,6313,6306,6305,6326,6319,6290,6302,6316,6307,6310,6326,6319,6305,6312,6320,6321,6313,6307,6302,6305,6310,6302,6300,6309,6309,6314,6321,6324,6317,6321,6336,6333,6319,6320,6334,6307,6303,6306,6313,6299,6314,6316,6288,6292,6310,6297,6303,6312,6296,6276,6288,6282,6290,6303,6302,6283,6290,6300,6317,6300,6297,6296,6296,6307,6323,6299,6303,6319,6319,6309,6323,6317,6307,6317,6309,6276,6299,6320,6288,6281,6321,6321,6312,6331,6354,6340,6344,6372,6367,6358,6381,6367,6358,6367,6376,6364,6364,6395,6398,6400,6419,6427,6422,6433,6450,6441,6433,6431,6423,6427,6437,6424,6403,6410,6415,6412,6409,6413,6403,6357,6371,6371,6347,6354,6360,6343,6338,6344,6345,6333,6326,6319,6306,6299,6312,6292,6276,6302,6306,6296,6320,6320,6312,6313,6327,6302,6297,6295,6297,6285,6323,6321,6312,6316,6343,6337,6307,6288,6262,6213,6233,6271,6282,6282,6266,6314,6396,6481,6605,6770,6971,7156,7289,7435,7637,7834,7981,8029,7905,7754,7653,7472,7186,6938,6764,6536,6324,6193,6161,6107,6109,6116,6123,6161,6219,6231,6248,6282,6306,6309,6327,6338,6343,6331,6351,6352,6340,6354,6336,6314,6341,6357,6357,6374,6386,6361,6355,6379,6372,6362,6368,6361,6352,6376,6398,6391,6384,6375,6393,6378,6398,6403,6382,6364,6385,6392,6396,6416,6426,6403,6407,6422,6419,6424,6427,6393,6385,6410,6410,6393,6424,6444,6437,6426,6450,6460,6460,6485,6486,6470,6479,6503,6501,6484,6502,6522,6537,6551,6546,6522,6540,6574,6589,6579,6596,6588,6598,6608,6639,6644,6656,6664,6675,6675,6691,6692,6704,6725,6726,6716,6719,6720,6720,6733,6742,6718,6718,6752,6757,6715,6701,6715,6702,6719,6719,6674,6671,6682,6675,6668,6667,6658,6654,6636,6634,6601,6572,6568,6554,6520,6539,6509,6470,6477,6498,6468,6443,6438,6436,6422,6424,6409,6384,6386,6395,6386,6364,6375,6392,6384,6375,6362,6374,6368,6384,6372,6369,6375,6379,6362,6384,6386,6367,6375,6384,6376,6374,6376,6358,6358,6382,6391,6378,6362,6384,6393,6381,6391,6403,6393,6388,6407,6385,6388,6398,6385,6396,6410,6398,6374,6388,6407,6382,6379,6405,6398,6384,6384,6391,6389,6400,6393,6395,6384,6395,6384,6384,6413,6399,6367,6374,6393,6382,6379,6399,6386,6372,6369,6381,6386,6393,6398,6381,6368,6391,6384,6378,6386,6382,6361,6364,6379,6368,6358,6365,6357,6347,6355,6364,6344,6350,6360,6329,6334,6355,6337,6320,6324,6337,6316,6326,6338,6324,6320,6338,6333,6331,6345,6329,6310,6329,6352,6313,6305,6317,6310,6296,6299,6303,6290,6290,6292,6279,6283,6312,6310,6316,6321,6316,6295,6326,6347,6309,6296,6313,6299,6302,6314,6316,6302,6305,6305,6305,6306,6324,6307,6283,6305,6293,6293,6310,6309,6303,6306,6323,6314,6317,6326,6331,6333,6350,6344,6330,6343,6361,6347,6348,6374,6368,6343,6367,6391,6381,6395,6415,6393,6372,6386,6386,6386,6391,6395,6378,6350,6355,6345,6350,6372,6352,6320,6309,6305,6279,6275,6309,6314,6275,6288,6306,6276,6274,6281,6274,6248,6262,6247,6233,6238,6254,6259,6261,6285,6275,6275,6269,6259,6258,6257,6258,6230,6234,6244,6248,6276,6283,6257,6231,6240,6231,6193,6176,6195,6219,6231,6226,6251,6303,6378,6485,6618,6798,6976,7135,7270,7442,7624,7808,7918,7887,7726,7593,7486,7268,7011,6801,6581,6350,6186,6118,6069,6044,6039,6034,6062,6114,6142,6154,6193,6221,6214,6234,6265,6254,6247,6265,6272,6252,6257,6262,6240,6241,6264,6262,6255,6283,6274,6251,6248,6255,6237,6235,6247,6241,6241,6261,6272,6259,6281,6290,6265,6262,6274,6250,6245,6252,6247,6243,6266,6272,6262,6276,6288,6274,6282,6297,6289,6274,6285,6288,6275,6290,6316,6330,6321,6316,6313,6320,6345,6358,6329,6323,6334,6341,6347,6361,6360,6371,6402,6410,6405,6422,6438,6438,6438,6457,6454,6443,6458,6481,6478,6484,6505,6516,6532,6556,6546,6541,6567,6578,6568,6575,6589,6567,6571,6601,6611,6589,6609,6615,6599,6605,6603,6578,6572,6587,6572,6560,6557,6560,6537,6536,6540,6516,6508,6503,6486,6448,6444,6444,6412,6396,6388,6371,6348,6354,6341,6299,6312,6307,6281,6272,6274,6261,6247,6250,6244,6223,6223,6219,6221,6221,6226,6217,6209,6220,6227,6206,6207,6221,6207,6196,6204,6199,6185,6189,6196,6186,6195,6203,6188,6188,6203,6200,6196,6221,6221,6196,6188,6219,6202,6211,6214,6200,6189,6196,6202,6195,6202,6214,6207,6204,6224,6202,6193,6217,6220,6210,6209,6210,6197,6203,6217,6206,6199,6214,6219,6207,6204,6227,6211,6210,6223,6210,6211,6237,6240,6226,6227,6224,6219,6227,6245,6238,6221,6227,6235,6219,6224,6235,6213,6217,6248,6234,6220,6234,6227,6210,6241,6257,6238,6227,6227,6227,6214,6233,6243,6221,6221,6235,6233,6228,6238,6237,6228,6233,6233,6227,6231,6238,6224,6230,6235,6226,6214,6248,6254,6233,6238,6226,6211,6224,6228,6223,6213,6220,6210,6200,6217,6221,6223,6224,6240,6247,6233,6241,6235,6238,6247,6257,6245,6234,6251,6252,6243,6248,6248,6235,6250,6251,6231,6231,6250,6248,6237,6252,6258,6261,6275,6289,6288,6279,6303,6296,6295,6302,6288,6281,6299,6317,6302,6292,6326,6336,6330,6351,6368,6355,6375,6371,6330,6327,6352,6350,6351,6334,6323,6307,6319,6330,6312,6303,6310,6290,6265,6262,6264,6244,6261,6275,6247,6247,6269,6251,6248,6248,6237,6220,6210,6223,6209,6202,6204,6206,6207,6220,6248,6219,6217,6230,6217,6204,6221,6216,6203,6209,6217,6216,6230,6235,6210,6176,6175,6161,6135,6144,6173,6179,6188,6216,6265,6341,6482,6625,6791,6988,7167,7330,7531,7712,7896,8012,8013,7868,7706,7592,7396,7127,6878,6644,6412,6234,6155,6103,6058,6047,6061,6072,6114,6155,6182,6213,6233,6228,6233,6261,6268,6255,6257,6261,6251,6245,6259,6238,6237,6255,6275,6264,6269,6274,6259,6237,6261,6243,6233,6245,6258,6238,6241,6258,6269,6268,6292,6283,6251,6258,6269,6264,6269,6283,6274,6264,6293,6289,6282,6289,6306,6295,6297,6302,6288,6278,6306,6303,6288,6317,6333,6310,6324,6343,6340,6338,6364,6362,6345,6357,6362,6334,6351,6384,6375,6379,6405,6400,6392,6430,6455,6440,6443,6454,6450,6460,6482,6491,6486,6496,6516,6527,6546,6548,6547,6550,6579,6577,6564,6581,6589,6582,6598,6608,6599,6587,6622,6611,6589,6608,6605,6577,6578,6596,6581,6553,6570,6572,6554,6556,6543,6510,6501,6499,6482,6454,6444,6424,6407,6388,6379,6364,6355,6350,6329,6312,6307,6300,6279,6265,6265,6257,6258,6266,6245,6217,6235,6244,6233,6235,6233,6210,6220,6224,6223,6214,6234,6228,6209,6214,6221,6214,6217,6230,6231,6193,6209,6223,6223,6226,6226,6213,6226,6220,6207,6210,6228,6223,6200,6214,6219,6204,6214,6223,6217,6206,6220,6227,6216,6211,6216,6207,6220,6235,6224,6204,6219,6226,6211,6220,6223,6203,6197,6217,6219,6203,6213,6213,6203,6217,6220,6204,6204,6209,6196,6179,6199,6200,6188,6204,6211,6192,6192,6216,6213,6195,6202,6204,6192,6197,6200,6186,6188,6204,6189,6182,6203,6206,6185,6175,6197,6180,6183,6206,6210,6192,6207,6209,6189,6206,6221,6209,6204,6209,6206,6193,6206,6209,6209,6206,6213,6200,6216,6234,6210,6185,6202,6227,6210,6204,6221,6203,6203,6213,6213,6202,6220,6219,6210,6214,6210,6192,6192,6206,6206,6188,6197,6196,6183,6199,6216,6200,6206,6231,6223,6216,6243,6237,6231,6238,6248,6245,6248,6255,6248,6251,6264,6265,6248,6243,6247,6233,6241,6261,6245,6223,6234,6258,6266,6275,6292,6275,6286,6314,6321,6309,6303,6305,6295,6300,6317,6306,6310,6323,6326,6326,6365,6382,6384,6386,6388,6360,6348,6369,6364,6348,6350,6331,6316,6321,6334,6313,6306,6324,6320,6286,6268,6272,6257,6252,6266,6258,6257,6275,6258,6230,6243,6245,6224,6217,6213,6193,6195,6217,6213,6202,6221,6245,6238,6235,6240,6230,6223,6226,6221,6195,6210,6228,6231,6250,6257,6237,6214,6207,6185,6152,6155,6173,6186,6196,6214,6228,6297,6420,6551,6720,6929,7110,7277,7473,7671,7860,8021,8119,8044,7864,7737,7590,7334,7048,6799,6556,6343,6204,6133,6080,6056,6035,6054,6114,6168,6173,6213,6252,6258,6238,6261,6276,6271,6278,6293,6281,6251,6257,6264,6254,6271,6275,6266,6276,6297,6282,6271,6272,6262,6268,6275,6274,6264,6272,6302,6290,6289,6310,6300,6303,6316,6299,6283,6285,6306,6296,6300,6313,6312,6319,6347,6348,6329,6331,6352,6343,6338,6350,6351,6338,6348,6369,6367,6374,6402,6393,6388,6402,6409,6389,6407,6410,6399,6417,6430,6426,6440,6461,6464,6471,6503,6503,6496,6508,6529,6517,6520,6547,6550,6548,6582,6608,6609,6612,6629,6637,6656,6680,6673,6660,6667,6675,6677,6687,6701,6694,6681,6706,6711,6681,6692,6699,6684,6677,6685,6660,6660,6677,6674,6654,6649,6649,6632,6606,6602,6582,6565,6561,6532,6498,6501,6491,6455,6441,6451,6429,6410,6403,6393,6365,6361,6362,6347,6348,6362,6324,6306,6314,6323,6305,6312,6313,6296,6299,6307,6288,6276,6295,6299,6290,6282,6289,6288,6296,6300,6283,6295,6317,6313,6293,6306,6303,6279,6296,6316,6282,6268,6286,6296,6281,6290,6288,6271,6282,6302,6275,6275,6289,6282,6265,6282,6282,6261,6262,6279,6274,6264,6266,6255,6254,6269,6269,6257,6251,6271,6259,6252,6271,6276,6247,6268,6276,6261,6258,6279,6274,6262,6275,6274,6248,6258,6275,6264,6259,6264,6254,6245,6259,6258,6244,6258,6261,6241,6247,6261,6252,6252,6258,6269,6257,6257,6250,6240,6230,6259,6262,6233,6237,6243,6241,6261,6259,6250,6248,6264,6252,6233,6257,6261,6238,6240,6254,6251,6247,6252,6238,6234,6250,6259,6238,6243,6244,6237,6244,6262,6259,6240,6245,6245,6234,6248,6261,6237,6216,6241,6243,6230,6250,6234,6221,6244,6257,6231,6217,6241,6238,6235,6247,6240,6220,6245,6251,6243,6233,6247,6241,6235,6250,6235,6219,6237,6241,6228,6213,6223,6226,6226,6228,6240,6230,6243,6240,6234,6235,6255,6248,6240,6254,6251,6233,6245,6254,6252,6251,6261,6257,6247,6261,6257,6235,6243,6257,6257,6248,6264,6245,6252,6269,6282,6271,6292,6307,6307,6300,6317,6297,6282,6303,6320,6305,6297,6297,6297,6324,6351,6341,6347,6382,6391,6379,6368,6369,6355,6367,6389,6376,6348,6350,6354,6337,6348,6351,6340,6327,6307,6276,6265,6283,6289,6276,6290,6289,6276,6265,6276,6275,6250,6258,6252,6221,6209,6221,6220,6227,6250,6247,6245,6259,6262,6235,6231,6247,6235,6221,6238,6234,6221,6248,6259,6241,6247,6238,6206,6176,6178,6155,6171,6206,6207,6206,6261,6350,6440,6584,6801,6984,7158,7339,7541,7734,7950,8109,8114,7998,7853,7727,7541,7286,7015,6760,6525,6313,6178,6125,6094,6054,6037,6073,6123,6147,6168,6199,6228,6247,6268,6255,6257,6282,6288,6271,6276,6278,6266,6257,6278,6282,6281,6288,6299,6289,6293,6303,6279,6265,6276,6275,6265,6272,6297,6286,6290,6314,6297,6299,6320,6316,6303,6296,6300,6312,6314,6324,6319,6319,6344,6344,6336,6336,6337,6324,6327,6331,6327,6327,6333,6341,6334,6364,6372,6362,6384,6396,6385,6378,6395,6395,6391,6406,6416,6395,6412,6446,6436,6437,6464,6472,6472,6492,6481,6471,6493,6525,6513,6529,6544,6546,6553,6578,6591,6591,6606,6620,6612,6613,6620,6627,6629,6646,6643,6634,6649,6671,6646,6634,6670,6657,6640,6636,6633,6623,6616,6629,6602,6594,6606,6595,6575,6584,6570,6534,6529,6529,6501,6475,6474,6450,6409,6410,6410,6378,6367,6355,6338,6324,6326,6320,6290,6295,6293,6276,6265,6276,6268,6248,6251,6251,6255,6257,6247,6233,6238,6258,6252,6243,6252,6240,6227,6240,6252,6244,6234,6247,6230,6233,6243,6241,6238,6243,6255,6234,6226,6243,6244,6241,6250,6247,6226,6233,6244,6234,6233,6243,6234,6221,6244,6241,6217,6231,6244,6234,6233,6243,6231,6224,6241,6238,6220,6237,6244,6221,6228,6251,6221,6211,6231,6231,6209,6214,6231,6214,6209,6219,6211,6207,6214,6216,6211,6217,6221,6196,6195,6216,6207,6202,6207,6209,6199,6197,6211,6189,6188,6217,6207,6196,6206,6203,6186,6200,6206,6189,6186,6200,6189,6175,6189,6190,6175,6192,6204,6179,6185,6199,6179,6179,6196,6189,6178,6188,6192,6183,6182,6204,6195,6188,6206,6211,6188,6182,6192,6209,6197,6190,6182,6180,6207,6199,6182,6199,6213,6193,6197,6226,6214,6200,6216,6204,6202,6211,6210,6206,6202,6210,6195,6178,6195,6211,6197,6203,6199,6183,6180,6193,6182,6190,6202,6197,6182,6195,6209,6193,6193,6223,6231,6220,6226,6216,6209,6216,6238,6221,6224,6244,6230,6221,6224,6227,6227,6227,6234,6224,6210,6224,6219,6223,6235,6241,6235,6259,6281,6275,6266,6290,6295,6283,6272,6268,6261,6275,6290,6268,6257,6286,6307,6319,6351,6364,6362,6367,6361,6350,6338,6341,6338,6336,6331,6314,6279,6286,6300,6300,6300,6299,6269,6240,6241,6240,6231,6248,6251,6241,6226,6226,6220,6217,6217,6199,6166,6172,6176,6156,6154,6173,6189,6180,6197,6206,6189,6197,6202,6172,6162,6176,6179,6156,6156,6180,6188,6188,6182,6151,6131,6133,6109,6073,6090,6120,6123,6142,6168,6210,6303,6441,6602,6773,6966,7170,7337,7541,7739,7927,8035,8013,7841,7692,7575,7344,7034,6777,6557,6313,6130,6056,5996,5956,5952,5972,5993,6041,6078,6085,6110,6159,6161,6149,6171,6171,6156,6173,6178,6165,6161,6175,6161,6145,6166,6193,6182,6188,6192,6183,6158,6164,6148,6149,6171,6175,6171,6180,6199,6200,6202,6224,6219,6204,6203,6204,6175,6182,6202,6193,6197,6216,6219,6223,6226,6231,6243,6244,6241,6227,6221,6233
```

(Note: These are the split values from the file that is mentioned inthe program)

This is the values that I get from my ECG machine, I need to find out the P,Q,R,S,T peaks in these data produced.

```
def findHighPeaks(A,count):
pivots   = [i for a,(i,b),c in zip(A,enumerate(A[1:],1),A[2:])
                            if a>b and b<c or a<b and b>c]
iWaves = [(left,mid,right) for left,mid,right
                           in  zip([0]+pivots,pivots,pivots[1:]+[len(A)-1])]
peaks  = [(A[left],A[mid],A[right]) for left,mid,right in iWaves
                                    if A[left]<A[mid]]
highPeaks = set(sorted(peaks,key=lambda p:p[1])[-count:])
return [p for p in peaks if p in highPeaks]

import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f=open( "D:/sharefolder narasima/New folder/ECG20201005172540.sh","r" )
Raw_file=f.read()
start_data=Raw_file.find("<ECG data>")+len("<ECG data>")
end_data=Raw_file.find("</ECG data>")
Sorted_data=Raw_file[start_data:end_data]
A=Sorted_data
x = re.split('~|#\*#', A)
lead_2_data= [list(filter(None, i.split(","))) for i in x if  ":" not in i]
Device_data = [list(filter(None, i.split(","))) for i in x if  ":" in i]
ECG_data=([x for x in lead_2_data if x])
array=[list (i)for i in zip(*ECG_data)]
lead_2=(array[1])
A = list(map(int, lead_2))
Q,R,S = zip(*findHighPeaks(A,13))
print("R=",R)
print("Q=",Q)
print("S=",S)
for x in Q,R:
     plt.plot(x)
for y in R,S:
     plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(R)
```

I have did till this, This code helps me find Q,R,S values. I need to find out the values of P and T too, In this program I need to give the count value. Is it possible to get the count value automatically.

I too tried using neuro kit library but it was not quite helpful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a free coding service. Provide a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there are algorithms to calculate P,Q,S,T peaks. But here is a simple method to get all the Rpeaks. Refer to this [documentation](https://biosppy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for more information

```
>>> pip install biosppy

>>> import biosppy

>>> a = list(ecg_raw_data) #ecg_raw_data = Data you provided in the question
>>> ecg = biosppy.signals.ecg.ecg(a)

>>> rpeaks = ecg['rpeaks']

>>> array([ 562,  996, 1419, 1840, 2271, 2702])
```

Comment: Yeah @darth baba , this method can be used to detect the R-Peak alone. I need to find all the peaks in it. I had used neuro kit library for it. it detects P and T alone . I got stuck in finding all the peak points.

Comment: Are you sure your code is producing correct results for R-peaks?

Comment: Yeah @darth baba, but it has limited the peaks by sample rate

Comment: Check out the [code](https://github.com/PIA-Group/BioSPPy/blob/master/biosppy/signals/ecg.py) and there are actually codes there for how to get the  P, Q, S, and T positions. I think they're just not updated on the docs.

Do a Ctrl/Cmd+F and search `def get` and they'll appear!